# Strange behaviour when trying to render template with jsrender

Tags: templates, jsrender

I'm using a JSRender template:

`<li><div><img src='{{>url}}' alt='pic{{:#index+1}}'/>{{if description}}<p>{{>description}}</p>{{/if}}</div></li>`.

The data that I want to render is the following:

`var data = [{  url : '/some/picture.jpg' ,description: 'lorem ipsum'  },{  url : '/some/picture.jpg' ,description: 'lorem ipsum'  } ,{  url : '/some/picture.jpg' ,description: 'lorem ipsum'  },{  url : '/some/picture.jpg' ,description: 'lorem ipsum'  },{  url : '/some/picture.jpg' ,description: 'lorem ipsum'  },{  url : '/some/picture.jpg' ,description: 'lorem ipsum'  }];`

But the html actually rendered is the following (for each one):

`<li><div><img src='/some/picture.jpg' alt='pic{{:#index+1}}'/></div></li>`

even though there is the description property in the array.

I'm using an old version of JSRender (I don't even know the version), I tried to change it but it causes greater problems (there are problems in the initialization). I also tried this in the http://www.jsviews.com/ 'Try it' section and the result is different from the one I get, and it's the expected one. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If the result is correct in the http://www.jsviews.com/ 'Try it' section, then there must be something wrong in your code for invoking the template render.

Can you put your version on a jsfiddle, or show your complete code here - and make sure you are using the latest JsRender, e.g. from here: http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsrender.js